# Does npm install also builds the library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm

I have a question, about npm. [also tried on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/42lfuh/does_npm_install_also_builds_the_library/).

Let's take [jQuery npm](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) as an example.
When I `npm install jquery` I find a `jquery` folder inside my `node_modules` folder,
in it I find `dist` even though it is ignored in `.gitignore`.

Here is a look at the package's scripts:

```
"scripts": {
"build": "npm install && grunt",
"start": "grunt watch",
"test": "grunt && grunt test"
},
```

Grunt is used for the build by yet - not found in my `node_modules` (using npm5).

Where the duck is `dist` folder coming from??

Took jQuery as an example though I've seen many packages like this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you look at your .npmignore file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does npm install also builds the library?

In general: It depends. You can specify an `install` script in the [`scripts` section](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) in the `package.json` file, which is executed when someone runs `npm install <package>`, but this is advised against:

> Don't use `install`. Use a `.gyp` file for compilation, and `prepublish` for anything else. You should almost never have to explicitly set a `preinstall` or `install` script. If you are doing this, please consider if there is another option. The only valid use of `install` or `preinstall` scripts is for compilation which must be done on the target architecture.

---

For jQuery in particular it seems that it is (manually) built *before* it is published to npm. jQuery uses [grunt](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.2.0/Gruntfile.js) to build the library. This will generate the `dist` folder:

```
    build: {
        all: {
            dest: "dist/jquery.js",
            minimum: [
                "core",
                "selector"
            ],
```

More importantly, jQuery has an [`.npmignore`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.2.0/.npmignore) file, which means that this file is used over `.gitignore` when publishing the package on npm. As you can see, it does *not* exclude the `dist/` folder, hence that folder is included when publishing the to npm.

So it seems that someone runs these steps to publish a new version of jQuery:

```
npm run build
npm publish
```